# Blank page after login redirection React.js

Tags: reactjs, redirect, router

I have a small issue after the login it routes me to /dashboard, but I get a blank page. But if I just refresh the page using the same route /dashboard, the page is loading correctly.

I have created a copy of my project in sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/event-react-3r96m

Could you please have a look and help me?
I'm trying to keep the session after the login using a token, but for the sandbox I've inserted a dummy IF using user = email@test.com and password = test.

Thank you in advance!
Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you are not updating the `isLoggedIn` variable in app.js within the Auth component.

Add the following function in the app.js file.

```
  setLoggedIn = () => {
    this.setState ({isLoggedIn: true});
  }
```

change the following:

```
            {!this.state.isLoggedIn && (
              <Route path="/auth" component={AuthPage} exact />
            )}
```

to

```
            {!this.state.isLoggedIn && (
              <Route exact path='/auth' render={(props)=>
                <AuthPage {...props} updateStatus={this.setLoggedIn} />}
              />
            )}
```

in the Auth.js file inside the `handleSubmit` function call the new function passed in as props.

```
this.props.updateStatus();
```

Here's the sandbox. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/event-react-dzs9x

Note that I changed the localStorage calls since it was giving me an error.